# How can i use my azosans custom downloaded fonts in HTML pages with css property font-family

Tags: html, css

I have tried a lot to put custom azo-sans fonts in my HTML Pages, but it didn't work and not apply in my HTML pages.

```
**Here, i have put some css property which i have tried.**


@font-face {
  font-family: AzoSansWebReg, sans-serif;
  src: url('../fonts/rui-abreu-azosans-regular.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: AzoSansWebLight, sans-serif ;
  src: url('../fonts/rui-abreu-azosans-light.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: 200;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: AzoSansWebMed, sans-serif ;
  src: url('../fonts/rui-abreu-azosans-medium.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: 600;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: AzoSansWebBold, sans-serif ;
  src: url('../fonts/rui-abreu-azosans-bold.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: 800;
}

What are things i need to change to apply this font in my HTML pages.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you seem to be adding your font the right way.  I'm assuming you've checked your url routes, yes?  If all that seems well, then all you need to do to apply these fonts is to use them like any of the other fonts:

```
body {
  font-family: 'AzoSansWebLight', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

I highly recommend checkout out the CSS-Tricks page on this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

CSS-Tricks is an awesome website that is overflowing with good knowledge and tricks.  Good luck!